# A how a MVC design pattern in PHP works with objects

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I created my own simple MVC system based on some tutorials. It works great, but I'm not sure what happens to my controller object after it is created. It works pretty much the same as any MVC framework.

1) I go to www.wherever.com/users/registration

2) users is my controller and registration is my action

3) The router makes sure the users class exists and that is has a registration method that is callable

4) Once those things are determined to be true, it instantiates the user class and set the new object to a variable called $controller_object and calls $controller_object->registration();

5) Finally, the registration method of the object is run where it calls the users model class to interact with the database and renders everything in the browser using the users view.

That's pretty much how they all work as far as I know. So, my question is, what happens to that $controller_object variable? I was thinking that from within a method of my model class I could access a property of the object by using $controller_object->first_name, but I get an error that the $controller_object does not exist. Shouldn't I still be able to access the users object from outside the object in that way?

Comment: If you didnt pass the variable $controller_object to your "model class", then you cant access it of course. Your explaining us your system and ask us how it works without showing us any code at all. LOL?

Comment: It depends on how and where you instantiate the object. Is the `$controller_object` variable available to the global scope? Is your view using the global scope or is it part of an object? If it's part of an object then you'd need to pass in `$controller_object`. Unfortunately you haven't given us any code to work with so it's impossible for us to know.

Comment: Are you having trouble rendering a view after invoking the controller?

Comment: Oh of course! If I make the $controller_object variable global it should work. Sorry, I should have thought of that, it's pretty obvious. See @Xatenev sometimes simple English is all you need. LOL

Comment: @keithmj: No its not. People were just guessing randomly around asking questions to somehow get any information. Making any variable `global` is **no** solution. Its bad practice. Instead you should inject the $controller_object if its needed, see **dependency injection**

Comment: @Xatenev Sorry to sound so negative. I don't have the code in front of me right now. Basically, the router class gets the controller and action from the URL and goes $controller_object = new User(), then $controller_object->registration() and ends. The issue is that the reference to the object ends with it. I want to keep that reference, $controller_object, so I can get to the properties of it from outside the object. In other words, from the model class I can do something like $first_name = $controller_object->first_name. I can't do that if I lose the reference to the object